# PostgreSQL: Problems decoding \uxxxx strings?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a number of strings that come to my application in what appears to be some kind of a Unicode version of string encoding.

This is one example of the encoding:

```
str = 'Hello, \udcd8yvind'
print(str)
```

When I print it, it seems that Python 3 automatically converts it to UTF-8:

```
Hello, �yvind
```

But that's wrong, it should print the following old Norse name instead, using the correct vowel Ø, which is a letter used in the Danish, Norwegian, Faroese, and Southern Sami languages. Like this:

```
Hello, Øyvind
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to convert this \udcd8 characters and similar, using Python to proper characters, even though I am semi-certain that every string that comes to me in this format is using ISO 8859-1 
 8-bit character encoding.

These strings came from some old text from the Usenet posts. 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Any ideas on how to encode this ISO 8859-1 character and print it correctly? Or detect the proper encoding for this type of strings?

Comment: Where did the original string come from?  In Python 3, printing it results in `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd8' in position 7: surrogates not allowed` for me.

Comment: These strings came from some old text from the Usenet posts. MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: hmm, `b'\xd8'` is  `'Ø'` in latin-1.  `b'\xdc'` is `'Ü'`.  Could the text have gone through multiple encoding/decoding steps?

Comment: \udcd8 is INVALID CHARACTER, that gets printed as a question mark. Your data in `str` is corrupted and there is no way that you can guess what the original character was.

Comment: If you control all the processing, can you share some example code that shows how you get from the original text to this?  (or share the location of the original data, if it's online).

Comment: It's a second post on this page: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adobe.after.effects/Is$20there$20any$20way$20to$20make$20gradient$20transparency$20masks$20in$20AE$3F%7Csort:date/adobe.after.effects/u9N_5ImKPxY/9n-lmVESuzYJ
But even google seems to have issues decoding it in their text interpretation even thought their original seems correctly parsed, not sure how they did that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/adobe.after.effects/u9N_5ImKPxY/9n-lmVESuzYJ

Comment: My original looks like this: From: =?unknown-8bit?q?=22=D8yvind_Schei=22_=3Cstratyon=40schei=2Eno=3E?=

Comment: How are you  downloading it?  (your last comment looks like quoted-printable btw - see quopri module in the stdlib)

Comment: I am getting this from mbox backups made by giganews

Comment: I am getting it in quoted printable format it seems. The last example I posted.

Comment: Interesting, I am able to convert quoted printable =D8yvind to a proper string Øyvind. Thanks for leading me onto a proper path. It seems that mbox parser in Python is causing the issue by converting this character from quoted printable into \udcd8. Some issue there.